# Backup баз данных MySql

Tags: unix, резервное-копирование, mysql

Итак, prerequisites:

- сервер на CentOS (хотя неважно - любой FreeBSD, Linux подойдет);
- запущенный mysql со стандартными настройками и кучей баз от разных пользователей;
- базы хранятся в /var/lib/mysql/. Там куча каталогов по пользователям, в каждом файлы MYD/MYI/frm

Известно, что если делать копирование файлов с живым сервером MySql ничего хорошего не выйдет, т.к. файлы будут "битыми". Нужно или тушить сервер (не годится) и копировать файлы, или придумывать хитрый способ слить базу в файл бекапа (напр., сделать выгрузку из базы).

Задача:

- Требуется обеспечить прозрачное резервирование баз данных mysql
- При этом нельзя сервер mysql остановить.
- Бекап необходимо производить с определенной регулярностью (возьмем, раз в неделю) в определенный каталог.
- Старые резервные копии можно не удалять: места достаточно.

Вот. В общем, такая вот задачка.

Comment: Решил проблему через админ-панель DirectAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К ответу от Сергея могу добавить вот что

> Вы можете использовать ключ `--all-databases` а отдельно придется дампить таблицу INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Подробные функции [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

А еще есть утилита (perl-script) [mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlhotcopy.html) (поддерживает регулярные выражения, поэтому дампить всё не составит труда)

Comment: mysqlhotcopy - практически то, что доктор прописал. Есть, правда, нюанс, что если база как-то живет, но не хватает каких-то файлов, mysqlhotcopy валится:

DBD::mysql::db do failed: Can't open file: './xxx_yyy/xxx_yyy_zzz.frm' (errno: 24) at /usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy line 452.

Comment: А вы посмотрите зависимости, устанавливаются они просто - http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/cpan_module_install.txt.html Это нормальное явление для Perl скриптов

Comment: Так проблема не в модулях перла - все есть. А в отсутствии некоторых некритичных файлов для работы БД. Т.е. по схеме они вроде как должны быть, а по факту файлов нет. Автоматический Repair их не создает.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump -uLOGIN -PPORT -hHOST -pPASS DBNAME > dump.txt
```

Забиваем в cron (вроде бы он отвечает за запуск по расписанию).

Comment: Много пользователей с кучей разных паролей. Решение нравится, но крон-файл будет слишком большой. К тому же при удалении-добавлении пользователей и баз данных придется это все редактировать. Неудобно, короче.

Comment: Напишите sh скрипт который бы по списку собирал данные разных пользователей. Тут я не подскажу их писать пока не умею.